# Get the id of the ul a certain li element is belonging to

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a nested `<ul> <li>` arrangement created dynamically. All these are assigned ids during creation. With a known `<li>` id how can I find the first `<ul>` element it meets and get its id.

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div></div>
    </li>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div></div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div></div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <li>
      <div></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

alert(document.getElementById(known_li_id).parentNode.nodeName);
//This returns UL , how do I get the id I assigned during creation
```

Comment: I not able to see `id` on any element. Please edit your question with relevant code.

Comment: Besides from not having any id's at all, this HTML is invalid. You cannot place a `<ul>` directly inside another `<ul>` without an `<li>` in between.

Comment: id s are assigned dynamically , I get the id of the li using click event. I will try your code and see

Comment: `.closest('ul').attr('id')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/).

If I understood your question correctly you are looking for [`parents`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) with filtering selector.

So your code should look like this:

```
jQuery(function($){
  $(function(){
    var ul_id = $('#my_known_id').parents('ul').first().attr('id');
    console.log(ul_id);
  });
});
```

Comment: with [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) your code could be much shorter

Answer (score 0):

change `nodeName` to `id` in your code

```
<div><ul>
             <li><div></div></li>
                        <ul>
                            <li><div></div></li>
                            <li><div></div></li>
                        </ul>
             <li><div></div></li>
       </ul>


     alert(document.getElementById(known_li_id).parentNode.id);
     //This returns UL , how do I get the id I assigned during creation
```

Comment: `<li>` nodes may not necessarily have an `id` attribute, that could be the menu and OP may refer to particular list item within click handler or select that by particular `textContent`, and since `jquery` tag is specified `.closest('ul').attr('id')` would be much shorter

Comment: I do not know jQuery. My solution for his specific case where he will make a minor change in his code. And his case that the parent has an id.